# Multi-language-tag support bug: other multi-language posts disappear on toggle!

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

For questions, (like [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36207/why-is-this-%E3%81%A7-wrong-and-%E3%82%92-preferable-%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%B7%E3%82%92%E5%B7%A6%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99?noredirect=1#36208)), where multiple posts use tags like #English or #日本語 to provide multiple language versions, if I click on the language toggle (eg "English" to switch to the English version of a post), the actual contents of other multi-language posts disappear entirely.  However, the meta-information and language toggle buttons remain on these other posts.

Work-around: clicking one of the language buttons of a "disappeared" post will restore its contents.

More details:
For "disappeared" posts, none of the language buttons is underlined, which suggests maybe the problem is that post is being rendered in a "null" language for which there is no data.

Comment: reproduced, looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

There was an issue in the `japanese-l-u.js` script. The fixed script will be available as soon as build rev `2016.6.28.3711` rolls out.

### Detective work

The `$.each` function returns [String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) as `this` when using it to iterate over an object.

[image: jquery each on object]

Furthermore, the above is a result of `.bind`/`.apply`/`.call` operations on a string primitive in JavaScript:

[image: javascript bind to string]

And of course, calling the equals operator on two String objects, even though they have the same value, returns `false`:

[image: comparison]

The fix was pretty straightforward:

[image: fix]

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response and the detective work!  I'll retest and mark accept once the change rolls out (assuming my memory doesn't fail me)

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy updated script is deployed, and working as expected on the [example post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36207/why-is-this-%E3%81%A7-wrong-and-%E3%82%92-preferable-%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%B7%E3%82%92%E5%B7%A6%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99?noredirect=1#36208)

Comment: Working on my end as well.  Many thanks !